# Remote Desktop (to Linux) Display Issues

Tags: display, resolution, remote-desktop

I'm using Windows Remote Desktop to connect to a Linux server. Both the Remote Desktop client and "xrandr" on the server specify a 1920x1080 resolution. However, some display setting is wrong and the resulting setup is borderline unusable:
(a) I can only access the top ~20% of the screen or so, but programs can appear below that
(b) So, if a program can't minimize to the top 20% of the screen, I can't interact with it
(c) Either the calendar button or Firefox icon is repeated multiple times at the top and the workspace switch UI is repeated multiple times at the bottom

The issue appears with other remote clients, so I think it's some setting I accidentally set on the server.

How do I debug/fix this? Other info + images below

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 256 x 256, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
rdp0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     50.00*
```

```
uname -r
3.10.0-1160.49.1.el7.x86_64
```

[image]